# Error when linking OpenGL program

Tags: c, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL programming. I installed Ubuntu 64bit OS and installed all required libraries. But today when compiling I got stuck with an error for which I'm unable to find a solution

When I compiled my program with this command:

```
cc aa.c -lglut  -lGLU -lGL
```

the following error appeared

```
/urs/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCVosZx.o: undefined refrence to symbol 'cos@@GLIBC_2.2.5' //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to link to the math library explicitly with `-lm`.

Comment: Explicitly.. u mean? in command line like     cc aa.c -lglut  -lGLU -lGL -lm or how?